# Bug in new "spoiler" CAPTCHA

Tags: bug, captcha

Background:

I typed a comment for a questions, and then decided to make it an answer when it grew longer and more detailed than appropriate for a comment.

**Steps**:

I copied and pasted my comment into the submission form, extended it, and pressed *Submit* button. The spoiler CAPTCHA came up, which mystified me for a couple of seconds. Then I accidentally dismissed the CAPTCHA (not quite sure where I clicked to do so) without answering it, and the question opened in a new window with my answer present.

> This is a spoiler

[This is the Question on DBA.SE where the issue occurred](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50821/optimize-in-clause-in-where-query-with-order-by-mysql)

Comment: What is a spoiler CAPTCHA?

Comment: OK, I think I know what happened. The CAPTCHA opens in a popover, non modal, dialog. Clicking anywhere in the screen outside the dialog dismisses it. You clicked the "Post Your Answer" button below the dialog and this time it submitted, since the CAPTCHA appears only if you post the answer too fast.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: A captcha in a spoiler (see my edit above) is what I termed a spoiler captcha.

Comment: I tried to reproduce and [this is what I got](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MomAA.png). No spoiler there, unless I miss something?

Comment: I suspect that you weren't logged in, then an authentication cookie was detected and the page was reloaded. Possible?

Comment: @Sklivvz I don't think so, this is what I get when doing what you said: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p9NOA.png (no matter how fast I click the button)

Comment: @Sklivvz: I was definitely logged in - I had been browsing the site for several minutes prior.